# Using Oracle Rank function

Tags: oracle

select product_name,start_tm,end_tm,load_date,bus_dt from A.product

Output :

```
Product_name   start_tm              end_tm               Load_date    bus_dt
Pencil        01-jul-21 12:00 am     01-jul-21 12:30 am   03-jul-21    01-jul-21
Pencil        01-jul-21 04:00 am     01-jul-21 04:30 am   03-jul-21    01-jul-21
Eraser        01-jul-21 01:00 am     01-jul-21 01:30 am   01-jul-21    02-jul-21
Eraser        01-jul-21 04:00 am     01-jul-21 04:30 am   02-jul-21    02-jul-21
```

If Product is Eraser then output should be latest load_date

```
Product_name   start_tm              end_tm               Load_date    bus_dt
Eraser        01-jul-21 04:00 am     01-jul-21 04:30 am   02-jul-21    02-jul-21
```

If Product is Eraser then output should be latest load_date since load_date as same
for product Pencil then it should look for Max end_tm

```
Product_name   start_tm              end_tm               Load_date    bus_dt
Pencil        01-jul-21 04:00 am     01-jul-21 04:30 am   03-jul-21    01-jul-21
```

how to achieve it using Rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it all, I believe. Sample data in lines #1 - 14; query begins at line #15.

```
SQL> with product (product_name, start_tm, end_tm, load_date, bus_dt) as
  2    (select 'pencil', to_date('01.07.2021 00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  3                      to_date('01.07.2021 00:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  4                      date '2021-07-03', date '2021-07-01' from dual union all
  5     select 'pencil', to_date('01.07.2021 04:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  6                      to_date('01.07.2021 04:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  7                      date '2021-07-03', date '2021-07-01' from dual union all
  8     select 'eraser', to_date('01.07.2021 01:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
  9                      to_date('01.07.2021 01:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
 10                      date '2021-07-01', date '2021-07-01' from dual union all
 11     select 'eraser', to_date('01.07.2021 04:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
 12                      to_date('01.07.2021 04:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),
 13                      date '2021-07-02', date '2021-07-02' from dual
 14    ),
 15  temp as
 16    (select p.*,
 17       rank() over (partition by product_name
 18         order by load_date desc, end_tm desc) rnk
 19     from product p
 20    )
 21  select *
 22  from temp
 23  where rnk = 1;

PRODUC START_TM         END_TM           LOAD_DATE        BUS_DT                  RNK
------ ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------
eraser 01.07.2021 04:00 01.07.2021 04:30 02.07.2021 00:00 02.07.2021 00:00          1
pencil 01.07.2021 04:00 01.07.2021 04:30 03.07.2021 00:00 01.07.2021 00:00          1

SQL>
```